# difficulty determining how to use external modules in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an application that I've written in typescript, and a few parts of it I want to use in another application. My immediate go to thought was to package those pieces up in an external module.

I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to do this right; the problem seems to be that if I package the classes and interfaces up, I'm unable to get another typescript application to recognize them unless I split off the interfaces into their own `*.d.ts` files and scope them with a namespace, like this...

### identity.d.ts

```
declare namespace mod {
   export interface IIdentity { /* ... */ }
   export class Identity implements IIdentity {}
}
```

and then the implementation...

### identity.ts

```
import 'mod';
```

It works fine if I do it this way, but it introduces a few problems - mostly because this *exact* design is spoken out as a bad one on the typescript documentation. But if I do not scope them like this, the only other way to get these interfaces and classes into another project is to literally copy them over and make them part of the entire program file hierarchy, or do excessive and obtuse file pathing (such as `import '../../../../../../../../../{file}'`) and I really want to make them more portable.

Is there anything else I can do? How is the correct way to wrap them into external modules without having to define everything in two places, and still make them callable?

Basically I really don't want this;
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I do not scope them like this, the only other way to get these interfaces and classes into another project is to literally copy them over and make them part of the entire program file hierarchy, or do excessive and obtuse file pathing (such as import '../../../../../../../../../{file}') and I really want to make them more portable.

The module should be made a `node_module`. Covered here : http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typings-for-npm-packages.html and here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: I'm not using nodejs at all. Does that make a difference?

Comment: alright. let me be more clear. I am using nodejs __only__ during development to load code. The actual program will not have nodejs on the server. Does that make a difference? It is a web application running on ASP.NET.

Comment: It makes a difference because the type lookup needs to match the runtime lookup. If your runtime location is not something under `node_modules` then the you need to load with full relative path. Which is what you already figured out 

Comment: So do I need to make each piece as a separate project, compile them into node modules, and then host them somewhere so I can install them like node modules? I'm a bit confused. How should they get to the `node_module` folder? Do I just use `gulp` to move the files in there?